# How can I make this a prepared Statements code?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I was under the impression that this was a prepared statement script, but it appears I was wrong. How can I turn this into one? What is a prepared statement?

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT Status FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_GET['username'], $_GET['password']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row or remove while loop if you wish
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<b style='color:green'>Found</b>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Try removing the singles quotes around your variable.

Comment: this is not prepared statements

Comment: This has nothing to do with prepared statemenets and there's no obvious syntax error in what you've posted. Which line, specifically, does it say has the error?

Comment: If you look at the syntax highlighting, it shows an unbalanced ".  End of where you set  $sql for the first time is missing a quote and ;

Comment: You still have a problem with quotes on the end of your prepare statement ( `"''` should be `"'"`)

Comment: Sorry Where is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not using prepared statements. This is a basic example with no error/result checking:-

```
$sql = "SELECT Status FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_GET['username'], $_GET['password']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

However you should consider selecting on username only and retrieving the password for comparison. You should also hash your passwords in the database if you're not doing so. Use php's `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for that. The former would help in hashing the password while the latter would be used to verify if the posted password from the html form or original source matches the hashed password

the syntax is

```
password_hash($_GET['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

password_verify($_GET['password'], $hashedPasswordFromDatabase);
```

make sure the column storing the password is `varchar(60)` at least.

Comment: I'm not sure what this means... would I have to change the password in the mysqli database?